# Оптимизация внешнего вида форм

Tags: c#, winforms, оптимизация, дизайн

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, можно как-то улучшить внешний вид форм, например, добавить градиент, эффекты (про WPF знаю, интересует именно Windows Forms).
Например, в Delphi была надстройка, которая позволяла использовать "темы" для интерфейса. Есть ли аналогичное в Windows Forms C#?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Можно, но если делать это самому, то в целом это долгое и муторно-рутинное занятие. Как вы, наверное, заметили, WinForms не предоставляет каких-то существенных средств по кастомизации интерфейса. В отличие от того же WPF описание внешнего вида там имеет императивный подход, а не декларативный.

Есть два основных пути. Первый - это писать самому все руками, создавая собственные контролы, занимаясь отрисовкой их вручную. Довольно унылый процесс. Вот в [этом обсуждении](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1234032.html) можете найти список статей, которые могут помочь вам в этом нелегком деле. 
Способ второй, более простой, но более платный. Для подобных целей (в том числе и под WinForms) существует ряд готовых решений, позволяющих легким движением превратить ваши брюки в элегантные шорты. Например контролы от [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) и от [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx). Они в основной своей массе не бесплатны (скажем, DevExpress для Winforms обойдется нынче в $899, минимальный пакет от Telerik - $999), однако же денег своих стоят - вряд ли сделать то же самое самому выйдет дешевле в плане затраченного труда (и не факт, что вообще выйдет). С другой стороны, если вы пишете какой-то собственный проект не на продажу, а исключительно для себя, то к вашим услугам пробные версии и кряки (Господи, прости меня, грешного).

Comment: +1, вот только WPF не зря придумали. WinForms морально устарел, учитесь делать приложения в WPF.

Comment: Ну, придумать-то его придумали, конечно, не зря, однако же автор вопроса говорит, что ему нужен именно WinForms.

Comment: А нужно ему именно WinForm, скорее всего, потому что ему лень учить WPF с его XAML и биндингом.

Я использовал и Telerik и DevExpress - тем оформления там не так много, по сути.

Comment: >А нужно ему именно WinForm, скорее всего, потому что ему лень учить WPF с его XAML и биндингом.

Зачем так категорично? Возможно, что имеется большой объем кода, написанного под WinForms, и переписывать его на WPF нет ни времени, ни ресурсов? Или есть ограничения типа требований заказчика/начальника/преподавателя.

Comment: Ну, первое вполне возможно, а второе - это уже вряд ли, сейчас все наоборот к WPF стремятся.

Comment: @z668, видимо, вам не доводилось сталкиваться с неподчиняющимися логике требованиями вышеобозначенных людей.

Comment: @DreamChild, к счастью нет, не приходилось.

Comment: @z668, вот видите, а вы сразу про лень.